# Prove that for every vector $V$, $||V||_{\infty} \leq ||V||_2 \leq || V||_1$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, numerical-methods

$\newcommand{\inf}{||V||_\infty}$
$\newcommand{\two}{||V||_2}$
$\newcommand{\one}{||V||_1}$

Prove that for every vector $V$, $\inf \leq \two \leq \one$

I have tried to look online for a solution to this question, but I only have figured out the easy part of it.

I know by definition:

- $\inf = \text{max}|x_i|$
- $\two = \displaystyle(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i^2))^\frac{1}{2}$
- $\one = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|$

Now, to me, it's obvious why $\inf \leq \one$. If the $\inf$ is the single maximum entry in the vector, and the $\one$ is the sum of all entries in the vector, it's clear that $\one$ contains $\inf$ in its sum. I suppose this logic would hold for why $\inf \leq \two$ also.

I'm having a hard time seeing why $\two \leq \one$.

Comment: Intuitively, $\| V \|_2 \leq \|V \|_1$ because it is easier to get from one corner of a rectangle to its diagonally opposite corner by cutting across the diagonal (as opposed to going the long way around and walking along part of the perimeter).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now that you know $\|V\|_{\infty}\leq \|V\|_1$, a simple argument would be:

$$
\|V\|_2^2 = \sum^{n}_{i=1} |x_i|^2 \leq \max_{1\leq i\leq n} |x_i| 
\left(\sum^{n}_{i=1} |x_i| \right)
= \|V\|_{\infty}\,\|V\|_1 \leq \|V\|_1^2
$$

Answer (score 8):

Compare the square of norms.

$||V||_2^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2$.

$||V||_1^2 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2 +  \sum\limits_{i < j}2|x_i||x_j|$.

Comment: things like this make me want to *facepalm*. Such a simple idea, but I probably never would have thought about it

Answer (score 2):

The following method is somewhat more cumbersome than those suggested by others, but has the advantage of working with other exponents.

First consider the case when $\|V\|_1 = 1$.  Then $\|V\|_\infty\le 1$ (as you've already shown), so all $|x_i|\le 1$, which implies $|x_i|^2\le|x_i|$.  Summing over $i$ and taking the square root yields $\|V\|_2\le\|V\|_1^{1/2}=1=\|V\|_1$.

Now consider the case $\|V\|_1\ne 0$.  Let $U=\frac1{\|V\|_1} V$; then $\|U\|_1=1$, so by the previous case, $\|U\|_2\le\|U\|_1$; multiplying by $\|V\|_1$ yields $\|V\|_2\le\|V\|_1$.

Finally, if $\|V\|_1=0$ then $V=0$, so $\|V\|_2=0$.